# Trying to Continue the program when it returns file not found exception in java

Tags: java

I i am able to read the lines from csv and download the images from url when the url is not having the image it is showing file not found exception in middle of the program i want to continue the program  with out terminating.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    InputStream inputStream = null;
    OutputStream outputStream = null;
    try {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("D:\\imgdwnld\\file.csv"));
        String line = br.readLine(); 
        while ((line = br.readLine()) !=null){
            URL url = new URL(line);
            inputStream = url.openStream();
            outputStream = new FileOutputStream("D:\\imgdwnld\\" +
                line.substring(line.lastIndexOf("/")));
            byte[] buffer = new byte[2048];
            int length;
            while ((length = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                outputStream.write(buffer, 0, length);
            }
        }
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        System.out.println("MalformedURLException :- " + e.getMessage());
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("FileNotFoundException :- " + e.getMessage());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("IOException :- " + e.getMessage());
    } finally {
        try {
            inputStream.close();
            outputStream.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Finally IOException :- " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't `return` when you catch the exception?

Comment: @AndréStannek `return` is redundant, it will end with or without it.

Comment: Please, please fix your indentation. This is close to being unreadable.

Comment: what you mean by `it is showing file not found exception in middle of the program` ? It's due to sysout in IOEXception catch block. And do not use return in a catch block.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik should have read the code more carefully ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the relevant outline of your code:

```
try {
  ...
  while ((line = br.readLine()) !=null) {
      ... process each CSV line ...
  }
} catch (IOException e) {
  ... handle it ...
}
```

At the place where you catch the exception you have already broken out of the main loop. Change the code to have this outline:

```
while ((line = br.readLine()) !=null) {
  try {
    ... process one CSV line ...
  } catch (IOException e) {
    ... handle it, the loop will proceed with the next line
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the "return" instruction from the corresponding catch (or maybe from the whole code). In your case, the instruction allows to "exit" the main method so the rest of instruction (those after the return statement) won't be executed.
Another tip is to separate this instructions in blocs. For example, if reading the CSV and the Img are not bound, you may need to encapsulate each treatment in an individual try-catch block. When parsing/reading the CSV file fails, your code may continue fetching the image.

Comment: FYI there's zero code following any of the `return` statements in the question. If OP removed all of them, the code would behave exactly the same. (OP has now edited the question, removing the redundant `return`s).

Comment: As I said, he may need to split his code into multiple blocks. In this case removing the returns is necessary ;)

Comment: As you said, "`You need to remove the 'return' instruction from the corresponding catch`"---untrue and irrelevant (the method will return with or without them). "`In your case, the instruction allows to 'exit' the main method so the rest of instruction (those after the return statement) won't be executed.`"---true and irrelevant (the "rest of instruction" equals zero).

Comment: Did you forget these lines !? "Another tip is to separate this instructions in blocs. For example, if reading the CSV and the Img are not bound, you may need to encapsulate each treatment in an individual try-catch block. When parsing/reading the CSV file fails, your code may continue fetching the image."

Comment: I chose to focus on the irrelevant and untrue statements you posted. You could markedly improve your answer by making it contain only relevant and true statements.